# Parse Cloud Code Setting Relation On User Class

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an issue with not getting some cloud code to run in Parse. Currently, I pass an objectId of another user who I want to set a review for. In client side, I am saving the review, and capturing that object. I pass that as well up to cloud code. Both show up there, but I cannot figure out the right way to set the relation on this user and apply that review that was created. Code snip is below. Any help would be appreciated before I bang my head against a wall.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addReview", async (request, response) => {
   let { userObjId, reviewObj } = request.params;

   const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

   //get the user object to post review of
   try{ 
      let object = await query.get(userObjId, {useMasterKey: true});         
      console.log(object);
      console.log("running");
      object.set('Reviews', new Parse.Object(reviewObj));
      object.save(null, { useMasterKey: true })
      return ("saved relation and updated reviews");
   } catch (err){
      throw new Error(err.message)
   }
});
```

Comment: not sure why a ' got added in on the code block, but fyi that is NOT present in code I am running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume

- `reviewObj` is the review object, the user recently created.
- and in your `User` class, you got a to-many-relation to `Review` class, named `'Reviews'`.

---

First I'd suggest to name your user object `user` instead of `object`, to make it clearer what you're dealing with and make your code easier to understand.

Since you said, the review object is already successfully saved on server side, I'd recommend to transmit only the reviewId in your request.

---

To add an object to a relation, you first need to get the relation property of your user object:
`const reviewsRelation = user.relation('Reviews');`

Then to add the object to the relation just call:
`reviewsRelation.add(user);`

In total, your snippet should look like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addReview", async (request, response) => {
   let { userObjId, reviewObjId } = request.params;

   const userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
   const reviewQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Review);

   //get the user object to post review of
   try{ 
      let user = await userQuery.get(userObjId, {useMasterKey: true});
      let review = await reviewQuery.get(reviewObjId, {useMasterKey: true});         
      console.log(user);
      console.log("running");
      const reviewsRelation = user.relation('Reviews');
      reviewsRelation.add(review);
      user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true })
      return ("saved relation and updated reviews");
   } catch (err){
      throw new Error(err.message)
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I tried to run the above and get "Error: schema mismatch for _User.Reviews; expected Relation<Reviews> but got Relation"

Comment: That sounds like `reviewObj` isn’t of type Review.class, is it? Is this just the id to the review?

Comment: @user1486736 I'd suggest to use the reviewObjID to query the review object. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Eureka! I had to change the review query line to "const reviewQuery = new Parse.Query('Reviews');" but otherwise, worked! Really appreciate the assistance!!

Comment: since you were helpful Robin, do you see any better way to optimize my query in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66359697/parse-cloud-code-job-function-optimization