# Parse Cloud Code Job Function Optimization

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, cron-task, back4app

I have a job on cloud code that I am running. It seems to work when I manually run the job. I think scheduling is posing an issue with its setup an frequency of running so I think it's unrelated to the actual code. Perhaps I'm wrong, but curious if there's a more efficient way to poll my parse class. I have an app where I am trying to find bookings that are coming up within the next hour from now(), and if there are send a push notification to the users within that class. Again, this runs but I think I may be able to optimize my query to only get items within that time frame vs more items that have a certain status.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateReviews", async (request) => {

var resultCount = 0;

// Query all bookings with a status of confirmed
var query = new Parse.Query("bookings");
query.equalTo("status", "confirmed");
const results = await query.find({useMasterKey:true});

results.forEach(object => {

    var users = [];
    users.push(object.get("buyerId"));
    users.push(object.get("placeOwner"));

    var today = new moment();
    var hourFrom = moment().add(1, 'hours');
    var startTime = moment(object.get("startTime"));

    if (startTime.isBetween(today, hourFrom)) {
    
        console.log("BETWEEN THE TIMEFRAME");
        resultCount += 1;

        users.forEach(sendPush);

    } else {
        
        console.log("NOT BETWEEN THE TIME FRAME, PASS OVER");
    }
});


return ("Successfully sent " + resultCount + " new notifications!");
```

});

function sendPush(value, index, array) {

```
var pushType = "bookingConfirmed";

let query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo("userId", value);
return Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
        title: "New Booking Coming Up",
        alert: "You have a booking coming up soon!",
        pushType
    }
},{useMasterKey: true});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It could be much better. I'd try something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.job('updateReviews', async () => {
  // Query all bookings with a status of confirmed
  const query = new Parse.Query('bookings');
  query.equalTo('status', 'confirmed');
  const now = new Date();
  query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('startTime', now);
  query.lessThanOrEqualTo('startTime', new Date(now.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000));
  const results = await query.find({ useMasterKey: true });

  const pushType = "bookingConfirmed";

  const pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.containedIn("userId", results.map(result => result.get('buyerId')).concat(results.map(result => result.get('placeOwner'))));
  await Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      title: 'New Booking Coming Up',
      alert: 'You have a booking coming up soon!',
      pushType
    }
  }, { useMasterKey: true });

  return (`Successfully sent ${results.length} new notifications!`);
});
```

Comment: This is only appearing to work when I remove one or both of the constraints on time. If I remove the greater than or equal it works. If I remove the less than or equal it works.

Comment: Could you please confirm the data type of the startTime field? Also, could you please send me an example of object that you believe should have been removed and wasn't ? Does the same object return only with greaterThan and only with the lessThan?

Comment: the data type is Date for startTime. I'm finding the whole job runs only when the lessThatOrEqualTo line is commented out after doing some line by line testing. I also tested commenting out the greaterThanOrEqual line to try and run the lessThan but that does not run. So it seems it's a problem with the lessThanOrEqualTo line.

Comment: It looks you have a type. It is not "lessThatOrEqualTo" but "lessThanOrEqualTo"

Comment: Was just a typo in describing, sorry. I can confirm it is lessThanOrEqualTo in the code

Comment: Got someone from support with my service to nudge me in the right direction on the setup. Rather than using the line above in the lessThanOrEqualTo, I am using:
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(d.getHours()+1);
query.lessThanOrEqualTo('startTime', d );

Comment: By doing `d.setHours(d.getHours()+1)`, you will have problem in the end of the day. Please do it with `query.lessThanOrEqualTo('startTime', new Date(now.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000));`. I've just updated the answer.

Comment: Good catch, that works too. I appreciate the help with this!